# Referring to dates other than \today

Tags: datetime

Is there a package that allows one to work with dates in the following way: just as `\date` shows today's date, I would like to have a command that dates the document 7 days from today.

Also, since I would like to use this as a template, I do not want to manually enter the dates myself. Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried the datenumber package?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

See the datenumber and advdate packages (and the datetime package for formatting options).

**Edit:** Added small example, essentially stolen from the datenumber documentation.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datenumber}

\begin{document}

\setdatetoday
\addtocounter{datenumber}{7}
\setdatebynumber{\thedatenumber}

Today is \today, 7 days from now it's \datedate.

\end{document}
```

Comment: It would be very helpful if you include an example (for 7 days from today, as in the question).

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\dayinmonth#1{%
  \ifcase#1 31\or28\or31\or30\or31\or30
            \or31\or31\or30\or31\or30\or31\fi}
\newcommand\Today[1][0]{%
  \advance\day by #1
  \edef\DiM{\dayinmonth{\the\month}}
  \ifnum\day>\DiM 
    \day=\numexpr \the\day-\DiM\relax 
    \advance\month\@ne
  \fi  
  \today}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\today -- \Today[30]

\end{document}
```

the year can also be tested if the month is 13 after increasing

Comment: NOTE: this solution has not considered a leap day (February 29). :-)

Answer (score 3):

It is perhaps worth showing an example using the `advdate` package, mentioned by Villemoes, as it has a single command solution for this, `\DayAfter[n]`, which prints the date *n* days ahead and leaves `\today` unchanged on exit. So for 7 days ahead:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{advdate}
\begin{document}

\today\\
\DayAfter[7]\\
\today\\

\end{document}
```

gives

```
     August 2, 2011
  August 9, 2011
  August 2, 2011
```

the `advdate` package also provides separate macros `\AdvanceDate` to change the value of `\today` to a number of days ahead together with `\SaveDate` and `\SetDate` to save and set the current value used for `\today`. `texdoc advdate` gives full details for these and other macros in the package, as usual.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: you can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code) as I did in my edit.

Comment: @don -- Thanks for the helpful comment. I have found and read the meta FAQs for this, e.g. [http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code), and the markdown help files so will be better placed if ever I have another piece of code to share :-)