# Automated age calculation

Tags: conversion, calculations, datetime

How can I calculate my age at compile-time in LaTeX?

Something like:

```
I'm \myage{day}{month}{year} years old.
```

would be most awesome.

Comment: This could be done using the `datenumber` package. The number of days would be easy. If you want to get "You are YY years, MM month and DD days old" it is more tricky. See also this [somehow related question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10358/2975).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can typeset your age easily using the `datetime` package and doing some simple calculations.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datenumber,fp}
\begin{document}
\newcounter{dateone}%
\newcounter{datetwo}%

\setmydatenumber{dateone}{1990}{01}{01}%
\setmydatenumber{datetwo}{\the\year}{\the\month}{\the\day}%
\FPsub\result{\thedatetwo}{\thedateone}
\FPdiv\myage{\result}{365.2425}
\myage

\end{document}
```

You can truncate the figure correctly, i.e., if you 21.6 years old it will give you 21 (see edit), by changing the last line of the code as follows:

```
\FPround\myage{\myage}{0}\myage\ years old
```

See also this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11425/function-like-macro/11430#11430).

**Edit**

Since the rounding of the age elicited a few comments I looked up the legal definition of age (which was probably appropriate in my example). Based on this I have changed the code from `FPround` to `FPtrunc`. Thanks to all that made comments. I also changed the days in the year to 365.2425 to increase the accuracy a bit for marginal cases!

Comment: Most people call themselves 21 years old until their 22nd birthday.  So `\FPtrunc\myage{\myage}{0}` might be more conventional.

Comment: Simon & Garfunkel have a song that goes "I was 21 years when I wrote this song.  I'm 22 now but I won't be for long.  Time hurries on, and the leaves that are green turn to brown."

Comment: @Matthew Good point, but given that most people around here are mathematically inclined I will leave the choice up to them.

Comment: Yannis answer with Matthew's addition is exactly what I was looking for. Big thanks for help :)

Comment: Not to be *too* pedantic, but the average year has 365.2425 days in it, [not 365.25](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year#Gregorian_calendar)—but I guess it doesn't matter unless you were born before 1900.

Comment: @Yiannis: This is _really_ not a matter of choice. If at all, it's a cultural question, but I don't believe _any_ culture will _round_. If you're 20.9 years old, you may choose to say "I'll soon be 21 years old", but in the cultures I know of, "I'm 21 years old" would be a lie (in particular in the US if you want to buy alcohol).

Comment: @Hendrik I know what you mean. Where I grew I had to jump straight from 18.01 to 21 many a times!

Comment: Need to beware of variable names too, Latex doesn't allow names like `var1` with numbers in them!

Answer (score 8):

The proposed solution does not seem to be completely accurate ; a perhaps more straightforward way of doing this is (replace DDMMYYYY by actual figures)

```
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcounter{myage}
\setcounter{myage}{\the\year}
\addtocounter{myage}{-YYYY}
\ifthenelse{\the\month<MM}{\addtocounter{myage}{-1}}{}
\ifthenelse{\the\month=MM}{
  \ifthenelse{\the\day < DD}{\addtocounter{myage}{-1}}{}
}{}
```

then `\themyage{}` can be used to show your age.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) You can highlight code by selecting it and pressing Ctrl + K.

Comment: Works well and is to the point. I couldn't make the accepted answer work because I need to compute the age before the beginning of the document and got an error.

Answer (score 3):

I have found that this works very nicely.

```
%
\catcode`@=11
\newcount\@tempnuma
\def\@null{null}
\def\age#1{\@age#1\@null}
\def\@age#1/#2/#3\@null{%
        \@tempnuma\year
        \advance\@tempnuma by -1900 % Comment this line out for dates of
                                    % the form 2/24/1967 - last 2 digits of yr.
        \advance\@tempnuma by -#3\relax  % gives # of years 
        %\number\@tempnuma
    \ifnum#1 > \month   %anniv month is later in year
            \advance\@tempnuma by -1\relax
    \else
            \ifnum#1 = \month   %anniv month is this month
                \ifnum#2 > \day %anniv day is later in month
                    \advance\@tempnuma by -1\relax
                \fi\relax
            \fi\relax
    \fi\relax
\number\@tempnuma}
\catcode`@=12
%
```

Usage is:  \age{6/25/84}  yields the correct age in years, which is what one usually wants.  With some twiddling, one could get the months and days.

Answer (score 0):

```
\usepackage{datenumber, fp}

\newcounter{birthday}
\setmydatenumber{birthday}{1995}{09}{06} % my birthday
\setdatetoday
\addtocounter{datenumber}{-\thebirthday} % today - birthday
\setdatebynumber{\thedatenumber} % get date
\FPsub\result{\thedateyear}{\thestartyear} % date year - start year (see datenumber lib doc)
\FPtrunc\myage{\result}{0} %truncate result

I am \myage years old.
```