# Date of file creation

Tags: datetime

When I write my notes, (I actually use lyx but that does not matter) I like to add a header with the name of file and the date the file was compiled. This I do using fancyhdr package and

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{\texttt{\jobname}}
\rhead{\textsf{\today}}
```

(to tell the truth in lyx I have to use `\jobname.lyx`, but, again, this does not matter).

The point is that it would be much more useful (at least for me) to be able to print the *date when the file was first created*. Is there a way in TeX/LaTeX to access the time information of a latex file? I can understand the answer might be OS dependent. I am actually using a linux distribution. I looked in many other forums/FAQ but could not find the answer so far.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! Note that you don't have to (and shouldn't) sign with your name since it automatically appears in the lower right corner of your post

Comment: On linux, there is no such thing as the date the file was first created. There are three timestamps on a file, known as mtime, atime and ctime. Here mtime is the time of last modification, atime is the time of last access, and ctime has a more technical definition that is irrelevant here.

Comment: Oops! You are right Harald, I na"ively thought ctime was creation time. Your observation preatty much nullifys my question. But I did find all the answer useful, I am sorry I can not vote them up.

Comment: Googling tells me that there is a "birthtime" and the stat command line utility under linux can display that time. Can't verify that, for I don't have a linux box right here.

Comment: @Patrick: Google is hardly an authority here. Both man pages for stat (ch 1 for the command, ch 2 for the system call) confirm that there are only the three time stamps I mentioned above.

Comment: @Harald: google is just a search engine for other web pages, and therefore never an authority. As I said, I couldn't verify. I am pretty sure that there _are_ linux systems out there that support btime/birthtime, but probably not from a default distribution. So that doesn't help lcv and is offtopic here anyway, so there is no need to discuss this any further.

Comment: @Patrick: In principle, the [ext4 filesystem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4) supports creation time, but I don't think this is already implemented in the system calls.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will work on linux, with `\write18` enabled; i.e., run using `pdftex --shell-escape`:

```
{\catcode`\%=12
\immediate\write18
 {/usr/bin/stat --format '\string\foo\space %yZ' \jobname.tex >\jobname.date}
 \def\foo#1 #2Z{\gdef\filedate{#1}}
 \input\jobname.date
}
The file is dated \filedate.
\bye
```

As I state in a comment above, you cannot get the file *creation* date, though. This gives you the file *modification* date instead.

Comment: Martin's answer surely makes more sense than this one. But I leave my answer here in case someone could use the technique for something related.

Comment: Yes this is the sort of answer I was thinking of. Thanks to Martin as well.

Comment: @Icv: My solution turned out to only return the file modification date, not the creation date as I thought at the beginning. So Harald's answer is the correct one. Note that you can write a `%` using `\@percentchar` which saves you the trouble of changing the catcode.

Comment: @Martin: No, my solution too gives modification date. Linux doesn't keep track of any creation date, so there is no way to get it.

Comment: Yes true, but under Windows such an approach should work and return the creation time. The difficulty might be to find a `stat` program under Windows.

Answer (score 11):

**Update:** In the meantime I published the [`filemod`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/filemod) package which can display and compare file modification dates. With this the modification date of the main file can be printed using `\filemodprint{\jobname}`.

---

pdfTeX provides the expandable primitive `\pdffilemoddate` which takes the file name in question as argument:

```
\pdffilemoddate{filename.tex}
```

or

```
\pdffilemoddate{\jobname.tex}
```

This works with all files, not just PDFs like the name might suggest.
It expands to the file modification date. The format is like `D:20110228133815Z`, which then can be parsed using a macro. Note that all characters of this string have the catcode *other* not *letter*.

The following code defines a macro which reads every number of the returned string an finally passes it to a format macro which can be freely redefined.
For help with formatting the date see [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10358/2975) or other questions tagged with [datetime](/questions/tagged/datetime).

```
\newcommand*{\filedate}[1]{%
    \expandafter\filedateX\pdffilemoddate{#1}\relax
}
\def\filedateX#1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8{%
    \filedateXX{#3#4#5#6}{#7#8}
}
\def\filedateXX#1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8{%
    \filedateXXX{#1}{#2}{#3#4}{#5#6}{#7#8}%
}
\def\filedateXXX#1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8\relax{%
    \formatdate{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6#7}%
}

\newcommand*{\formatdate}[6]{%
   #1-#2-#3\ #4:#5:#6%
}

\filedate{\jobname.tex}
```

Comment: I did not know about this. However, when I look for it in the pdftex documentation, I think you meant `\pdffilemoddate`, not `\pdfcreationdate`.

Comment: @Harald: Yes, you are right. I was under the impression that both are taken a file name as argument, which isn't the case. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For every document you write, the creation date is not going to change, by definition.

This means that it is perfectly acceptable to hard code the date in. For example,

`\rhead{\textsf{28\textsuperscript{th} Febuary, 2011}}`

or formatted however you want.
This would keep the date the creation date, because it doesn't need to dynamically change every time you compile the document.

If I have misunderstood what you want to do, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

There is 'getfiledate' package on CTAN and TeXLive.

`http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/getfiledate`

Comment: how can I use this stuff to just get the date, without any extra boxes, newlines, etc? I tried `\getfiledate[notime,datecolor=black,putprefix=false]{animalEstimation.tex}` but it creates some nasty new lines (this is inside the \date{} tag)

Answer (score 0):

If you are after the modification date, then the package [filemod](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/filemod) seems to do exactly what you need. To get the last modified date of the file you just include the package in the usual way:

```
\usepackage{filemod}
```

and the modification time of the current document is printed by:

```
\filemodprintdate{\jobname}
```

you can also print the modification time, and there are many options to format the output.

Comment: See the bottom of Martin Scharrer's answer; he's the package author `:-)`.

Comment: @HendrikVogt: Now at the top of my answer. Thanks for notifying me.