# Find changes in pdf directly

Tags: pdf, changes

I would like to track my corrections in the pdf format simply. Actually after every running I wanna avoid scroll to specified pages of changes.

is there anyway to manage that?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: Does one of the answers to [How to track changes between PDFs?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4548), ["Track changes" in LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/65453) or [Create a "List of Effective Pages"](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/127191) answer your question? If so, we could close this question as a duplicate.

Comment: No this is not my answer, actually my document is so long, after every changes and run I see pdf from first page, which is annoying every time scroll down to the same page of changes.

Comment: @MHP: That scrolling is as a result of the editor, not LaTeX. One could try to use [SyncTeX](http://itexmac.sourceforge.net/SyncTeX.html), but it may only be supported by certain browsers. See [What exactly is SyncTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/118489/5764)

Answer (score 2):

You could handle this via [SyncTeX](http://itexmac.sourceforge.net/SyncTeX.html). If your editor/viewer supports it, you can synchronize the position of the cursor in your source document with the position of the viewer.

[TeXstudio](http://itexmac.sourceforge.net/SyncTeX.html), for example (with the built-in viewer), supports it.